# What is the geometric interpretation of the identity $|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2=2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

---

This identity is simple to prove:

$|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2$

$=(z_1+z_2)(\overline{z_1+z_2})+(z_1-z_2)(\overline{z_1-z_2})$

$=(z_1+z_2)(\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2})+(z_1-z_2)(\bar{z_1}-\bar{z_2})$

$=(z_1\bar{z_1}+z_1\bar{z_2}+z_2\bar{z_1}+z_2\bar{z_2})+(z_1\bar{z_1}-z_1\bar{z_2}-\bar{z_1}z_2+z_2\bar{z_2})$

$=2(z_1\bar{z_1}+z_2\bar{z_2})$

$=2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)$

---

But what is the geometric interpretation of this identity?

Comment: The complex-geometry tag is for something totally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the interpretation you are looking for: the sum of the squares obtained from the diagonals of a parallelogram equals the sum of the squares obtained from its sides.

To be precise, the parallelogram we are talking about can be described by the next set of vertices:
\begin{align*}
V = \{0, z_{1},z_{2}, z_{1} + z_{2}\}
\end{align*}

It is indeed a parallelogram because the following relations hold:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
z_{2} - 0 = (z_{1} + z_{2}) - z_{1}\\\\
z_{1} - 0 = (z_{2} + z_{1}) - z_{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

As @dxiv has mentioned, such result is known as the parallelogram law.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I would like to up-vote here, but I think this answer could use more detail. Perhaps you should explain how this identity relates to parallelograms? A picture would be ideal, but even just a description in words of the vertices of the parallelogram, and how they relate to $z_1$ and $z_2$, would improve this answer.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the comment. I am going to improve my answer.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia You could also mention that it's commonly known as the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

Comment: +1 (It wasn't me that mentioned parallelogram law.)

Comment: @dviv: You have been here long enough to know that there is nothing "commonly known" here. In my former country and, I am sure, in China, Korea, etc. this law has no name at all. That's half  of the World population.

Comment: @markvs Fair point, then "commonly known" for certain values of "commonly" only ;-) Yet, it is useful terminology to be aware of, in both geometry and normed spaces contexts.